# Getting stdout from a tcpdump subprocess after terminating it

Tags: python, subprocess, tcpdump

I am running `tcpdump` in a subprocess like this:

```
pcap_process = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', '-s 0', '-w -', 'tcp'], 
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The `-w -` argument is important: it tells `tcpdump` to print the resulting .pcap file to `stdout`.

I then go on to access a website using `urllib.open()`. After this is done, I would like to kill `tcpdump` and put whatever it printed into a string. I have tried the following:

```
pcap_process.terminate()
result = pcap_process.stdout.read()    # or readline(), etc.
```

But (unless I'm doing something wrong), that doesn't work; I killed the process, now there's nothing left to be read. If I use `read()` or `communicate()` before terminating, my script will just sit there and read on and on, waiting for `tcpdump` to finish (which it won't).

Is there a way to do this (preferably without loops)?

Comment: You need to pass each of the parameters to `tcpdump` separately: `Popen(['tcpdump', '-s', '0', '-w', '-', 'tcp'], ...)`.  The single argument `-w -` does not get interpreted the same as the two arguments `-w` and `-`, etc.

Comment: True, that would've been the right answer :) Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using tcpdump, it's often advisable to use [PCAP directly](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/), or [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sniffing).

If that isn't an option, simply call `communicate` after `terminate` - killing a process does not kill data in the pipes to it. However, don't forget to separate arguments in the creation of the subprocess (`[,'-w', '-']` instead of `[... , '-w -', ..]`):

```
pcap_process = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', '-s', '0', '-w', '-', 'tcp'],
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately pypcap is not an option here :( ... if I do that, the output is empty. Maybe the problem is somewhere else ... ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @sebastian_k `'-w -'` writes into a file named `-`. You want either `'-w-'` or `'-w' '-'`. Updated the answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right on, what a silly mistake. Thanks a bunch, phihag! :)