# Python, how to read from stdout of ongoing process like tcpdump over Ubuntu

Tags: python, subprocess, tcpdump

I am trying to read from tcpdump output using python.
I am using subprocess to read from tcpdump stdout on fedora, redhat, SUSE, but actually my script doesn't work on Ubuntu.
my question sounds like this questionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163877/getting-stdout-from-a-tcpdump-subprocess-after-terminating-it, but actually, I don't find a proper solution..
This is my python code:

```
tcp_cmd = "tcpdump -i eth2 dst 224.1.1.1"

tcp_handle = Popen(tcp_cmd,shell=True,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

tcp_handle.terminate()

result = tcp_handle.stdout.read()`enter code here`

print result
```

Comment: always read() blocks on ubuntu I know reading from a process after killing it is not valid, but I didnt find another way

Comment: Is it only not working on Ubuntu or not working generally?

Comment: You kill the process right after you started it.  Maybe the process didn't have enough time to print anything yet?